# Tkinter no $DISPLAY or display name (Berkley pacman project)

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, cygwin, display

I am trying to use Berkley's [AI pacman projects.](http://ai.berkeley.edu/project_overview.html)
[Specifically this project.](http://ai.berkeley.edu/search.html)

A little bit about me: I'm on Windows 10 using `cygwin` as my terminal. I have both python and python3 installed as well as both versions of `Tkinter` and `tkinter` respectively. This project uses python 2.7. Trying to run the main project using the `python pacman.py` results in a long trace with the error being '_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable'.

Calling `echo $DISPLAY` outputs an empty string.

I believe this is the most relevant file:
http://ai.berkeley.edu/projects/release/search/v1/001/docs/graphicsUtils.html

I understand this is a relatively specific and difficult issue, but any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Edit: I have installed xwin and the relevant packages. I am able to start a server in one terminal with `startxwin` and then I try to run the same command in another terminal but arrive at the same issue. I believe my problem is that I cannot establish the xwin server as my $DISPLAY.

Comment: If you are using cygwin, then you need to run a X-server for Windows, like VcXsrv or Xming.

Comment: Cygwin has its own X server. Install ´XWin´ and ´xinit´ packages and start it with `startxwin`